# Problem compiling protobuf with clang 15.0.1 (Unable to find containing class of inner class)

Tags: c++, templates, clang, protocol-buffers

I am trying to compile a project that depends on Google Protocol Buffers with clang version 15.0.1. But I get a compilation issue:

```
include\google\protobuf\repeated_ptr_field.h(1155,1): warning G514CD124: Unable to find containing class "RepeatedPtrField" of inner class "TypeHandler". [other]
include\google\protobuf\repeated_ptr_field.h(1159,1): error G514CD124: Unable to find containing class "RepeatedPtrField" of inner class "TypeHandler". [other]
```

I have looked into `repeated_ptr_field.h`:

```
class RepeatedPtrField final : private internal::RepeatedPtrFieldBase {
// ...
private:
  class TypeHandler;
// ...
};

// ...

template <typename Element>
class RepeatedPtrField<Element>::TypeHandler
    : public internal::GenericTypeHandler<Element> {};

template <>
class RepeatedPtrField<std::string>::TypeHandler
    : public internal::StringTypeHandler {};
```

I don't see anything odd here (the innerclass `TypeHandler` is defined based on the specialization of the outher class). I don't understand why clang is not able to find the outer class. Has anyone an idea oder faced this issue before? Thanks in advance.

**[UPDATE]**

If I comment out the second specialization for testing

```
//template <>
//class RepeatedPtrField<std::string>::TypeHandler
//    : public internal::StringTypeHandler {};
```

the error disappears but I have other errors. I don't understand why clang has problems with the second specialization.